# Sync Music from Banshee via SSH to Android Device

Tags: ssh, banshee, music, android, transfer

i want to transfer my music to my android device via ssh. I do that wireless because i do not always want to plugin the cable to sync some files. Is there a way banshee can recognize my android device over ssh?

Or do you have any other solution to make that work?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like while gnomevfs supports accessing files on ssh servers like local ones the c# bindings banshee is using don't.

My guess (it is only a guess right now) would be that if you used fusefs to make the android device appear in /mount like an ordinary device would banshee would see this device. And if this device contained the .is_media_device file identifying it as an MP3 player it would actually use the device.

Let's give it a try (I have set up password-less authentification with my device using ssh keys, my local username is gunter, my username on my android device is root, and since this device isn't rooted ssh is running there on the non-standard port 2222)

```
sudo mkdir /media/Sulla.home

sudo chown gunter:gunter /media/Sulla.home/

sudo chmod a+r /etc/fuse.conf
```

...add the following line to /etc/fstab:

```
sshfs#root@192.168.182.33:/mnt/sdcard /media/Sulla.home fuse user,allow_other,port=2222
```

A final command at the command-line:

```
mount /media/Sulla.home
```

Now the device looks like an ordinary mounted device. Let's hope banshee will be convinced by this.

If this does not work, a possible workaround is to use the FolderSync extension with what we just mounted.

Answer (score 1):

There are Android apps to run an ssh server on your phone. You could install such an app, use sftp to connect to it from your computer, or mount your phone's filesystem on your computer with sshfs, and copy files to it that way.

There are alternatives that may be easier. I believe you can copy files using Bluetooth. You can install Dropbox on your phone, and link some or all of your music library to your Dropbox folder on the computer side -- the Android Dropbox client doesn't sync automatically, but only downloads when you actively choose to open a file, which is good for this application.

Comment: Thank you for this answer but thats not what i am searching for. I already have a SSH Server running on my device and the connection works greate.
When i am listening to music in Banshee and i like a song i want to transfer it quickly to my device. Right out of Banshee. I dont want to plugin a cable first. Neither i want to search for the folder which the song is located in to transfer it manually. 

Thats why i asked if there is any Banshee extension which integrates a SSH server as a mobile device right into Banshee to transfer Music to it.

Comment: have you found any extension or help regarding this? I also have an SSH server running on my Android and I so want to transfer music directly from Banshee without having to connect any cables

Comment: This would be a great feature to have as a music player plugin. My workaround is to ftp from the phone, but it's not integrated enough